# How to evaluate the definite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to evaluate the definite integral?

$$\int \frac{7}{3x+1}dx$$
I am having difficulties to finish the question:
Below is what I did:
$$ =\left.\frac{7}{3}\ln|3x+1|\right|_0^4$$
$$=\frac{7}{3}\ln(\dots.$$

Comment: Please [learn to use mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your mathematics more legibly.

Comment: You're almost there...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your integration is just fine:

All you have left to do is evaluate $$\dfrac 73 \ln|3x + 1| \Big|_0^4 = \dfrac 73 (\ln(13) - \underbrace{\ln(1)}_{\large = 0}) = \quad \frac 73 \ln(13) \quad \approx \quad5.985$$

Comment: I came with 1.536 which is wrong?

Comment: not correct 1.381

Comment: woops, I got 5.985 (I need to refresh my use of the calculator). Never worry about leaving answers as "exact", which is what you have with either of the two forms above.

Comment: thats correct thanks!!!. Can you tell me how you come to ln(13)?

Comment: Yes, we evaluate the integral at $x = 13$ and subtract its evaluation at $x = 0$. $x = 4 \implies \frac 73\ln(3x + 1) = \frac 73 \ln(3\cdot 4 + 1) = \frac 73 \ln(13)$. At x = 0, we have $\frac 73\ln(3\cdot 0 + 1) = \frac 73\ln(1) = 0$

Comment: Does that make sense now?

Comment: yes thanks. you are the best!!!

Comment: @amWhy: Great feedback! :-) +1

Answer (score 2):

Hint:take $u=3x+1\to du=3dx$$$\int_0^4\frac{7}{3x+1}dx=\frac73\int_0^4\frac{3dx}{3x+1}=\frac73\int_0^4\frac{du}{u}=lnu|_1^{13}=\frac73(\ln(13)-ln1)=\frac73(\ln(13)=\frac13\log_e {13^7}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I guessed correctly what you wrote (use LaTeX for mathematics in this site, please!):

$$\int\limits_0^4\frac7{3x+1}dx=\frac73\int\limits_0^4\frac{3\,dx}{3x+1}=\left.\frac73\log(3x+1)\right|_0^4=\frac73\left(\log13-\log1\right)=\ldots$$

Comment: I came with y= 1.536 which is wrong. Can you tell me your answer?

Comment: You have it there: $$\frac73\log 13\cong 5.9849$$ but I think it looks nicer as the left side... Also, why do you put that $\;y\;$ there??

Comment: when I use my calculator  (7)/(3)ln(13) I'm getting this answer: (7ln(13)/(3)

Comment: And that's correct, @SaraSharp .I'm afraid you don't quite know how to use that calculator, and perhaps using some parentheses and operations order would help. Try " log(13) * 7 =" , and then divide the result by three...